# How do you make java read and count the number of sentence input

Tags: java, validation

Sample output:

---

Enter the essay: I like cats.
Incorrect input! Your essay must contain at least 2 sentences, please
try again:

Enter the essay: I like cats. I like dogs.

Your essay contains 2 sentences.

---

This is my code so far:

```
System.out.print("Enter the essay: ");

String essay = input.nextLine();

do {
    System.out.print("Incorrect input! Your essay must contain at least 2 sentences, please try again: ");
    essay = input.nextLine();
} while (!(essay.contains(".")));

if (essay.contains(".")) {
    System.out.println("Your essay contains x sentences.");
}
```

There are many gaps and I don't know how to go about this program. Can you please help?

Comment: Can't I write each sentence in a new line?

Comment: Find all periods, and count them, then make a switch.

Comment: @Gendarme How do I do that?

Comment: @plantstho Regex, just match the pattern for period and find all the matches. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a somewhat complex regular expression to split, and take the length:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter the essay: ");

String essay = input.nextLine();
int sentenceCount = essay.split("\\S(\\s*[.!?])+(?!\\d)").length;

while (sentenceCount < 2) {
    System.out.print("Incorrect input! Your essay must contain at least 2 sentences, please try again: ");
    essay = input.nextLine();
    sentenceCount = essay.split("\\S(\\s*[.!?])+(?!\\d)").length;
}

System.out.printf("Your essay contains %d sentences.", sentenceCount);
```

[Live demo on Ideone](https://ideone.com/cSabkQ)

Note that this additionally counts other sentence-terminating characters, and rejects other inputs that obviously aren't 2 sentences, such as:

- ...
- I didn't write one!!
- WTF?!?!
- Pi is 3.14159.

Comment: @plantstho copy/pasted straight from the [help]: "Saying “thanks” is appreciated, but it doesn’t answer the question. Instead, vote up the answers that helped you the most! If these answers were helpful to you, please consider saying thank you in a more constructive way – by contributing your own answers to questions your peers have asked here."

Answer (score 1):

This should work, and if you use Java 8 you do not need countStringOccurrences method.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class util {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count = 0;
        String pattern = ".";

        System.out.print("Enter your sentence:\n");
        String  essay = input.nextLine();

        //this is supported in Java 8 . Otherwise you need to implement method 
        int howmany = countStringOccurrences(essay, pattern);
        System.out.print("how many : " + howmany + "\n");

        while ( !(essay.contains(pattern) ) || howmany < 2) {

            System.out.print("Incorrect input! Your essay must contain at least 2 sentence, please try again:\n ");
            essay = input.nextLine();
            howmany = countStringOccurrences(essay, pattern);
        }

        int i = 0;
        // Keep calling indexOf for the pattern.
        while ((i = essay.indexOf(pattern, i)) != -1) {
            // Advance starting index.
            i += pattern.length();
            // Increment count.
            count++;
        }

        System.out.print("Your essay contains " + count + " sentences");   
    }

    private static int countStringOccurrences(String essay, String pattern) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int i = 0;
        int count = 0;
        // Keep calling indexOf for the pattern.
        while ((i = essay.indexOf(pattern, i)) != -1) {
            // Advance starting index.
            i += pattern.length();
            // Increment count.
            count++;
        }

        return count;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter the essay: ");
String essay = scanner.nextLine();

while (essay.split("[.]").length < 2) {
    System.out.println("Incorrect input! Your essay must contain at least 2 sentences, please try again: ");
    essay = scanner.nextLine();
}
System.out.println("Your essay contains " + essay.split("[.]").length + " sentences");
```

Comment: changed split() argument to be regexp and simplified while loop

Comment: it looks at number of sentences now

Comment: Eh, sure, I'll throw in an upvote for the attempt. And also because I want the Sportsmanship badge and I don't get many opportunities for progress.

Comment: plus for honesty :)